# Redirect alias domain sub-folders to main domain sub-folders

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I just combined 2 domains into one. i used the phpMyADmin Alias domain
settings (maybe that's the issues) to point the domain to the hosting...

Now, I want old domain / alias domain pages to redirect to corresponding pages in the new domain - this is a `Wordpress` site

**I tried this**

```
redirect 301 gispan-online.co.il/some-category/ http://www.gispanjewelry.co.il/some-category/
```

**but it doesn't work.**
I don't know if the problem is that this is a `Wordpress` site
and need other setting or that the server catches the redirect
before htaccess is loading or that I am just doing it wrong

Would appreciate your help on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch directive :

```
redirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://www.gispanjewelry.co.il/$1/
```

Comment: this would just cause (checked, causes a loop) a loop. and.. i dont see how this helps me even if it did work.